# Command Prompt settings won't save

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, visual-studio, c++, c

I've tried running as admin and setting both `Defaults`' and `Properties`' window sizes. upon re-opening `cmd` the window is small again even though Default settings are still set right.

Also tried deleting the registries:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console
```

as I read online it resets the settings, but it didn't help.

I've got a C++ end of semester test next week and it's seriously disrupting my coding practice, if anyone has a fix for me I'll be incredibly grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend restarting your computer, opening only one instance of `cmd` when making the changes, and then closing that instance before testing if it worked. Running multiple instances of `cmd` when modifying `Defaults` might be the culprit.

When I was testing what could cause this problem, I experienced weird behavior when I started trying to adjust the `Defaults` and `Properties` while I had multiple instances of `cmd` running at once. For example the changes to `Defaults` didn't seem to affect new instances as expected.